# Is a child element set to visible while its parent set to hidden bad for SEO?

Tags: seo, googlebot, css

To modify the style of a component within a framework, I need to set the visibility of the parent container to hidden and the visibility of its child that contains the content to visible.

Is that bad practice for SEO? Do robots recognize that the text is visible even if its parent container is hidden? Or would it be seen as deceptive by Google (https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66353?hl=en ) ?

Comment: I thought that hiding a parent would hide everything in it?  How is a child showing?

Comment: I'm using the CSS visibility property. If the visibility is set to hidden: "the element box is invisible (not drawn), but still affects layout as norma. **Descendants of the element will be visible if they have visibility set to visible** "
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility

Answer (score 2):

Based on the link you provide.

Are you being deceptive? Meaning are you hiding the parent element in order to achieve keyword stuffing of some sort? This is really bad and I would't do it.

You aren't being deceptive but again some text (that might contain keywords) is being hidden along with the parent element? This is bad and I would't risk it.

Do you want to hide the parent element that does not contain any text just for design purposes. You are good to go.